# Metatable is not indexed, even though setmetatable is used

Tags: lua, lua-table, metatable, lua-5.1, lua-5.3

According to the Lua manual, setmetatable still works the same as in Lua 5.0. Yet for some reason, when I try this code in Lua 5.1.5 and 5.3.1, it appears that the metatable is not accessed:

```
ClassTable = {}
ClassTable.getString = function(self) 
  return self.x .. ""
end

inst = {}
setmetatable(inst, ClassTable)
inst.x = 7

--doens't work
assert(getmetatable(inst) == ClassTable)
print(inst:getString())
```

The first case works, however in the second case the I get the error which suggests that the metatable is not being used:

```
./lua: /test.lua:12: attempt to call method 'getString' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
    test.lua:12: in main chunk
    [C]: ?
```

This also has nothing to do with the method call operator ":" as even getting the value of the method doesn't go to the metatable.

```
print(inst.getString)
nil
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make the table `inst` access the metatable you need to use the metamethod `__index`.

So you can correct the code by adding this line at the top below `ClassTable.getString` definition:

```
ClassTable.__index = ClassTable
```

> Despite the name, the __index metamethod does
>   not need to be a function: It can be a table, instead. When it is a
>   function, Lua calls it with the table and the absent key as its
>   arguments. When it is a table, Lua redoes the access in that table.

- http://www.lua.org/pil/13.4.1.html

Comment: Setting __index in the instance object doesn't seem to work though. Does this mean __index is only checked in the metatable?

Comment: @stands2reason Yes. All metamethods need to be in the metatable. You may want to read through the reference about them because that is basically the first thing said about them: http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#2.4